# How to test services in an AngularJS Controller?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

My controller is:

```
angularMoonApp.controller('SourceController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', 'fileService', function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, fileService) {
  $scope.init = function() {
    $rootScope.currentItem = 'source';

    fileService.getContents($routeParams.path).then(function(response) {
      $scope.contents = response.data;
      $scope.fileContents = null;
      if(_.isArray($scope.contents)) {
        // We have a listing of files
        $scope.breadcrumbPath = response.data[0].path.split('/'); 
      } else {
        // We have one file
        $scope.breadcrumbPath = response.data.path.split('/');
        $scope.breadcrumbPath.push('');

        $scope.fileContents = atob(response.data.content);

        fileService.getCommits(response.data.path).then(function(response) {
          $scope.commits = response.data;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  $scope.init();
}]);
```

My test is pretty simple:

```
(function() {
  describe('SourceController', function() {
    var $scope, $rootScope, $httpBackend, createController;

    beforeEach(module('angularMoon'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
      $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
      $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();

      var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

      createController = function() {
        return $controller('SourceController', {
          '$scope': $scope
        });
      };
    }));

    it("should set the current menu item to 'source'", function() {
      createController();
      $scope.init();
      expect($rootScope.currentItem).toBe('source');
    });

    it("should get the contents of the root folder", function() {
      createController();
      $scope.init();

      // NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE!
    });

  });
})();
```

I want to test that the `fileService` had it's `getContents` function called and mock a response so that I can test the two scenarios (if is array and if isn't`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using Jasmine spies for this.

Here is an example that might help. I usually put the spyOn call in the beforeEach.

```
var mockedResponse = {};
spyOn(fileService, "getContents").andReturn(mockedResponse);
```

In the 'it' part:

```
expect(fileService.getContents).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

To get the response, just call the method in your controller that calls the fileService method. You may need to manually run a digest cycle too. Snippet from one of my tests:

```
    var testOrgs = [];
    beforeEach(inject(function(coresvc) {
        deferred.resolve(testOrgs);
        spyOn(coresvc, 'getOrganizations').andReturn(deferred.promise);

        scope.getAllOrganizations();
        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it("getOrganizations() test the spy call", inject(function(coresvc) {
        expect(coresvc.getOrganizations).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));

    it("$scope.organizations should be populated", function() {
        expect(scope.allOrganizations).toEqual(testOrgs);
        expect(scope.allOrganizations.length).toEqual(0);
    });
```

deferred in this case is a promise created with $q.defer();

Comment: Can you add a more complete example with `$q` and how you're using it?

Comment: Also ,what if you want to test 2 different responses?

Comment: Our services return promises to the controllers, so I had to mock the response as if it was a promise. Literally the only line missing is the var deferred = $q.defer(); When I want to test different mock outputs, I add a second test with a different mocked response. Sometimes I do call deferred.resolve(someMock); to control the output of the promise.

Comment: So if I want different data for different tests, I shouldn't put the spy in `beforeEach`, correct? Instead I should do it in the test?

Comment: You can have nested/multiple beforeEach. Each "test" (at least this is how I do it) has a beforeEach and some its.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a spy and verify only that `fileService.getContents` is called, or either verify extra calls (like promise resolution) by making the spy call through. Probably you should also interact with httpBackend since you may need to flush the http service (even though you use the mock service).

```
(function() {
  describe('SourceController', function() {
    var $scope, $rootScope, $httpBackend, createController, fileService;

    beforeEach(module('angularMoon'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
      $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
      $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();

      // See here
      fileService = $injector.get('fileService');
      spyOn(fileService, 'getContents').andCallThrough();

      var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

      createController = function() {
        return $controller('SourceController', {
          '$scope': $scope
          'fileService': fileService
        });
      };
    }));

    it("should get the contents of the root folder", function() {
      createController();
      $scope.init();

      expect(fileService.getContents).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

  });
})();
```

You can also add expectations to what happens inside the callback but you should issue a `httpBackend.flush()` before.

Comment: Calling through means you are now running real service code. That may not be what the OP wants. Usually in a unit test you would want to mock the response and avoid calling the actual service.

Comment: How can I mock a response? So sometimes I want `getContents` to return data X and sometimes data Y

Comment: @aet that's why said you *can* do that, not that you should do that. Usually you just want to know that the method was called and no further interaction matters.

Comment: @Shamoon I think aet already answered your question with the `andReturn` method.

Comment: @Pipetus i don't see `andReturn` in your answer

Comment: Not me, @aet's answer :)